# Don't get the pop-up form more the one time without refreshing

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-5

```
<!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                @* <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5> *@
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <--- My Form Loads Here ---->
                <div class="modal-body" id="partial_view_div">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <button id="CreateAirportForm">Create New</button>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('body').on('click', '#CreateAirportForm', function (event) {
        LoadNewAirport();
    });
    function LoadNewAirport() { 
        $('#exampleModal').modal('show'); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("LoadNewAirportForm", "Airports")',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#partial_view_div').html(data); 
                
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOption, thrownError) {
                alert("An error occurred while loading the partial view.");
            }
        });
    } 
</script>
```

For the first time after pressing on "Create New" button, the pop up form works fine. But on second time it does not work. If I refresh my page, then again it works fine for the first time, but in second time it does not work.

How can I solve this problem. I want get the pop up form as many times as I press on the "Create New" button.

Comment: i cant really see any problem in the code, or is there more code involved? can you make a codesnippet that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Protip: convention is to `id` your elements with what they are - `CreateAirportForm` *implies* `<form id=CreateAirportForm>`

Comment: 2nd protip: show your modal either with a placeholder loaded *or* don't show your modal until the ajax has completed - otherwise you get the old modal shown briefly as your new content is loaded

Comment: Assuming you only have *one* of the generically named `<div id=partial_view_div>` then it's likely that the issue is in code you've not provided - ie when you save from the popup, or more specifically *close* the modal.  It's likely you are destroying the modal instead of just hiding it.

Comment: Before `$('#exampleModal').modal('show'); ` add `console.log($('[id=exampleModal]').length)` and check the console as you test your page - first click this should be 1, second click (after closing the modal) it's *probably* 0.   ie *debug* your code don't just jump immediately to *"it doesn't work"*

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m for your reply.Adding **console.log($('[id=exampleModal]').length)** before **$('#exampleModal').modal('show');** I got 1 for firstclick but my second click show this error
**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
    at LoadNewAirport (Airports:88:28)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (Airports:82:9)
    at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (VM131 jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:43064)
    at v.handle (VM131 jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:41048)
LoadNewAirport @ Airports:88
(anonymous) @ Airports:82
dispatch @ VM131 jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
v.handle @ VM131 jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2**

Comment: That error usually means that jquery has been reloaded for some reason.  Make sure to check the network tab to be sure only the requests you're expecting are happening.  eg it should be obvious if the whole page is reloaded of just your GET ajax request.  If only the GET, then make sure jquery isn't included in the return from your `LoadNewAirportForm` action.